# Replace ONLY next to each other duplicates

Tags: arrays, algorithm

How to make replacement of next to each other ONLY `false` duplicates in array but don't touch the ones that seperate.

From this:

```
{false, false, false, false, true, true, false, true, false, false};
```

to this:

```
{false, true, true, false, true, false}
```

Comment: General approach: Pass 1: Extract subsequences; Pass 2: Build result from these. Iterate through and keep a start-index (marking start of false-subsequence) until hit true; add pair (start, end) to some list. New start-index introduced if observing new false-value. After this you got a list of (start-end) pairs. Fill a new result-list/array with one false per pair; add the truths of original array, between end_x,start_x_+1. Continue...

Comment: @sascha Can you give an example, i better understand example than words...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a smart method would be the following.

```
boolean[] myArray = {false, false, false, false, true, true, false, true, false, false};

// Introduce myArray[0] to your array result.
for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i-1] || myArray[i]) // Introduce myArray[i] to your array result.
}
```

You introduce the value if current value is `true`, or if the last one (controlled by `introduce` variable) was not `false`. First element is always introduced, because wether is true or false, the logic problem says to introduce it.

Also, I think it would go faster if you don't short-circuit `myArray[i-1] || myArray[i]` and let `myArray[i-1] | myArray[i]`. It is faster to check the second value of the or operation than make the **if instruction** at the compiler level to see if the first value is already true.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the next element and remove the current `false` only if next is `false`.At the same time you can make changes to the same array to remove duplicates.

```
int index=0;
for(int i=0;i<arr.size()-1;i++)
{
   if(arr[i]==false && arr[i+1]==false)
      continue;
   else //this should exist in array
   {
      arr[index]=arr[i];
      index++;
   }
 }
 arr[index++]=arr[arr.size()-1];//for the last element
 //Last element added irrespective of being true or false
 //Now you can remove the elements from index to end
 std::remove(arr.begin()+index,arr.end());
```

Comment: I think if last element of `arr` is true, it is not introduced in the result, when it should. Also if two last elements are true, false. The last false should also be introduced.

Comment: @SantiGil I think the last element will always be introduced in this code which will sort things.If last element is true it will be introduced.If there are two false at end the second last false won't be introduced while the last one will.

Comment: Ok! I didn't see `arr[index++]=arr[arr.size()-1]`

Comment: In fact we have the same algorithm, If you apply [Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): (yours) `arr[i]==false && arr[i+1]==false` = (mine) `arr[i]==true || arr[i+1]==true`

Comment: @SantiGil. Can you now remove the downvote(if this was the case for downvote).

Answer (score 1):

Using C++ and the standard library:

```
v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(),
                    [](bool a, bool b){ return !(a||b); }),
        v.end());
```

The standard library `std::unique` function compresses the collection by overwriting all but the first of a sequence of duplicates. In this case, we use a lambda function in order to avoid counting two consecutive `true` values as duplicates; only a pair of values such that `!(a||b)` is true counts, and that expression is only true if both `a` and `b` are false. (`!a && !b` would have worked just as well and very likely generates identical code.)

`std::unique` returns the end point of the compressed range; it is then necessary (or at least useful) to reduce the size of the container, which is what the `erase` member function does, assuming that it is implemented for the container `v` (here, I'm assuming that `v` is a `std::vector` but a `std::deque`  or `std::list` would work as well).

[Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/JJUi4x)

Comment: @BladeMight: Added whitespace and an explanation. It's really very simple.

Comment: Well now i understand, but it only for C++?

Comment: @blademight: yes, I fixed the answer to mention that.